# In my JavaScript, the plus button should always be under the last position

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, spring-boot

[see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqa4Z.jpg)

Now if I click the button(+), new buttons are added below the main button. I would like the added buttons(-) to be located above the main button(+). plus button should always be under the last position

JavaScript:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var max_fields = 50;  //maximum input boxes allowed
        var wrapper = $(".ilosc-wrapper"); //Fields wrapper
        var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
        function addFunc() {
            if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
                x++; //text box increment

            $(wrapper).append
            ('<div>' +
                '<div class="clearfix"><' +
                    'div style="float:left; margin-right: 20px;" class="ilosc">' +
                        '<p class="ilosc_text"><spring:message code="b2b.JRmainContent_mainContentProduct.quantity"/>:</p>' +
                        ' <input style="margin-top:3px;" type="number" min="1" class="productAmount" onchange="triggerValidation(false)" value="1">' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div style="float:left;" class="ilosc">' +
                        '<p class="ilosc_text">' +
                            '<spring:message code="b2b.JRmainContent_mainContentProduct.width"/>[m]' +
                        ':</p> <input type="number" min="${length}" class="productLength" onchange="triggerValidation(false)" value="0">' +
                        '<a style="margin-bottom: 2px; margin-left: 20px; padding: 4px 12px;" href="#" class="remove_field btn btn-danger" >-</a>' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</div>'+
                    '<div class="lengthValid" style="padding: 5px; margin-right: 84px; display:none;">' +
                        '<p id="par" style="color:red;"></p>' +
                    '</div>' +
            '</div>');
        }
    };

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $("body").on("click", '.add_field_button', function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        addFunc();
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
         e.preventDefault();
         $(this).parent().parent().remove(); x--;
    })

});
</script>
```

CODE:

```
<div id="glownydiv">
                    <div style="float:left; margin-right: 20px;" class="ilosc" id="iloscV">
                        <p class="ilosc_text">
                            <spring:message code="b2b.JRmainContent_mainContentProduct.quantity"/>:
                        </p>
                        <input type="number" min="1" class="productAmount" value="1">
                    </div>
                    <div style="float:left;" class="length-div" id="dlugoscV">
                        <p>
                            <spring:message code="b2b.JRmainContent_mainContentProduct.width"/>[m]:
                        </p>
                        <fmt:parseNumber parseLocale="pl" var="length" value="0">  </fmt:parseNumber>
                        <input type="number" min="${length }" class="productLength" value="${length}">
                    </div>
                </div>
```